# (VBA) How do i retrieve selected checkbox data from dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a form that has 2 buttons on it, the code captures the column titles from the Data sheet, adds to an array, then creates checkboxes renaming the captions according to the column titles. It then checks to see whether this information has previously been saved on the report sheet and pre-selects the checkboxes.

This all works in the code below, what I cant work out is when I press a button 'OKButn' to make it get the data selected data from these dynamically created checkboxes and add it to the array so I can output the results to the 
report sheet.

The code for this button is held on the forms code sheet - only way I could get the buttons working (that I know of). It would be good to create the buttons dynamically too - which I can do, but then get them running code after being clicked which I cant work out.

here is my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Public HdrArray(), HdrColArray()
Public z, y, TotalHdrs, SavedHdrsCol, SavedHdrsRow, TotalSavedHdrs As Integer
Public AddOption As Object


Sub PopulateForm()

ColumnCopyForm.Show vbModeless
ColumnCopyForm.Caption = "Column Copy Selection """

Sheets("Data").Select

'Find total number of headers
TotalHdrs = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Find cell that records the 'required columns'
SavedHdrsCol = Sheets("Report").Range("A1:zz100").Find("Required Columns", LookIn:=xlValues).Column
SavedHdrsRow = Sheets("Report").Range("A1:zz100").Find("Required Columns", LookIn:=xlValues).Row

'Count total rows
TotalSavedHdrs = Sheets("Report").Cells(Sheets("Data").Rows.Count, SavedHdrsCol).End(xlUp).Row

For z = 0 To (TotalHdrs - 1)
    'If Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1 + z).Value = "Item Type" Then
    'Delete Columns on Data Sheet
    'Sheets("Data").Columns(z).EntireColumn.Delete
    'Else

    'Makes the array dynamic
    ReDim Preserve HdrArray(TotalHdrs, z)

    'Adds the Data table header label to the array (column 0)
    HdrArray(0, z) = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1 + z).Value

    'Adds the column number to the array (Column 1)
    HdrArray(1, z) = z

    'Adds a check box - renaming it to the column title
    Set AddOption = ColumnCopyForm.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "LabelOpt" & z, True)
    With AddOption
        .Caption = HdrArray(0, z)
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 200
        .Top = .Height * z

        'Automatically selects this if the option has been previously saved to copy to report sheet
        For y = 0 To (TotalSavedHdrs - 1)
            If Sheets("Report").Cells(SavedHdrsRow + 1 + y, SavedHdrsCol).Value = HdrArray(0, z) Then
                AddOption.Value = True

                'Add info to Array
                HdrArray(2, z) = 1
            End If
        Next y
    End With
    'End If

    'Make button visible - and format
    ColumnCopyForm.OKButn.Visible = True
    With ColumnCopyForm.OKButn
        .Caption = "Apply & Close"
        .Top = ColumnCopyForm.Height - 50
        .Left = ColumnCopyForm.Width - 130
        .Width = 70
        .Height = 20
        .ZOrder (0)
    End With

    'Make button visible - and format
    ColumnCopyForm.CancelButn.Visible = True
    With ColumnCopyForm.CancelButn
        .Caption = "Cancel"
        .Top = ColumnCopyForm.Height - 50
        .Left = ColumnCopyForm.Width - 50
        .Width = 40
        .Height = 20
        .ZOrder (0)
    End With

Next z

End Sub
```

Here is the code  for the button...

```
Option Explicit

Sub OKButn_Click()

For y = 0 To (TotalHdrs - 1)
    MsgBox (HdrArray(0, y) & " - " & HdrArray(2, y))

    'Saves the preferences to the report sheet
    If HdrArray(2, y) = "1" Then
        Sheets("Report").Cells(SavedHdrsRow + 1 + y, SavedHdrsCol).Value = HdrArray(0, y)
    End If
Next y

Unload ColumnCopyForm

End Sub
```

This is the code I thought might work under the button...

```
Sub OKButn_Click()

    For y = 0 To (TotalHdrs - 1)
    Set LabelOptName = "LabelOpt" & (y + 1)

    If ColumnCopyForm.LabelOptName.Value = True Then
        HdrArray(2, y) = 1
    End If


    MsgBox (HdrArray(0, y) & " - " & HdrArray(2, y))
        'Saves the preferences to the report sheet
        If HdrArray(2, y) = "1" Then
            Sheets("Report").Cells(SavedHdrsRow + 1 + y, SavedHdrsCol).Value = HdrArray(0, y)

        End If

    Next y

Unload ColumnCopyForm
End Sub
```

However on this line:

> If ColumnCopyForm.LabelOptName.Value = True Then

I get a compile error:
Method or data member not found

Comment: Since it's only `OKButn_Click()` that's not working, start by declaring all your public variables with explicit data type and see if that helps. Also make sure the public declarations are in a module, not the forms code sheet.

Comment: Thanks, in the above code the button is working and the code within the button runs - picking up the public declarations and values which are in a module.

Its just getting the results from the checkboxes that I am unsure of how to get.

Comment: Error is specific to "LabelOptName"

Comment: Look at a for each loop to loop through the controls.

Comment: Labels have captions, not values. Try `ColumnCopyForm.LabelOptName.Caption` instead and set it equal to the text of the caption instead of a boolean.

Comment: Sorry the name I have given to the checkboxes is deceiving, I was trying to make LabelOptName be the name of the checkbox in the form.

Nathan is onto something with the for each loop though... I may have an answer shortly
Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working, thanks for the tip about Looping through the controls!

Here is the code on the button which does work...

```
Sub OKButn_Click()
z = 0
y = 0
'Loops through the controls on the form, to get values of the Checkboxes
   For Each ctlLoop In ColumnCopyForm.Controls
'Checks to see if the value is true so it can be recorded
   If ctlLoop.Value = True Then
   'Records the column title in the correct place for future referencing
      Sheets("Report").Cells(SavedHdrsRow + 1 + y, SavedHdrsCol).Value = HdrArray(0, z)
      y = y + 1

    End If
    z = z + 1
    Next ctlLoop


Unload ColumnCopyForm
End Sub
```